# VB6 Read All Values Under Registry Key

Tags: vb6, registry

In Visual Basic 6, how can I get all the values of keys under, for example:

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run

Which would return the following values (depending on user):

> "C:\Program Files\Steam\Steam.exe"
>   -silent
>
> "C:\Program
>   Files\Skype\Phone\Skype.exe" /nosplash
>   /minimized
>
> "C:\Program Files\Windows
>   Live\Messenger\msnmsgr.exe"
>   /background
>
> Etc...

As the keys are not constant, I do not know how to read these. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for the API function [RegEnumKeyEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724862%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) - you can find a VB example at MSDN [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/267908)

> [RegEnumKeyEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724862%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) Function
>
> Enumerates the subkeys of the specified open registry key. The function retrieves information about one subkey each time it is called.

Comment: Did you look at the example I posted in the link? It shows **exactly** how to read the keys.

Answer (score 2):

Look at here http://www.thescarms.com/vbasic/registry.aspx that is one excellent article for work with register of windows